# Дублирование методов в модулях в Ruby

Tags: ruby

Нужно добавить модуль, который добавляет объекту массив. Данный код почему-то не работает, доступа в методах к массиву @comments нет

```
module Library
  module Commentable
    attr_accessor :comments
    def initialize author, title
      @comments = []
      super author, title
    end
  end
end

class Library::Book
  include Library::Commentable
  attr_accessor :author, :title
  def initialize author, title
    @author = author
    @title = title
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что выходит, что **сначала вызывается `initialize` у `Library::Book`**, который *унаследованный* метод (из `Commentable`) **не вызывает** (`super` там нет).

```
Library::Book.ancestors
#=> [
#     Library::Book,       <-- он первый по списку
#     Library::Commentable,
#     Object,
#     Kernel,
#     BasicObject
#   ]
```

Если забыть о том факте, что "комментируемое" у вас почему-то принимает аргументы, характерные книге (потому что это деталь задачи, о которой вы ничего не рассказали), возможных выходов два:

1. (в Ruby 2.0 и новее) Заменить `include` на `prepend`, чтобы модуль оказался **впереди** всей цепочки поиска методов (разве что после метакласса, но это уже дебри).
2. Перенести вызов `super` в `Library::Book` (и вспомнить, что вызов `super` без аргументов и скобок прокидывает аргументы текущего вызова).

Answer (score 2):

Добавлю свои пять копеек. В модуле можно перезагрузить метод `included`, который выполняется каждый раз, когда модуль включается в другой модуль или класс при помощи инструкции `include`. В качестве аргумента методу передается класс, куда модуль был подмешан, что позволяет определить собственные методы:

```
module Library
  module Commentable
    def self.included(base)
      base.class_eval do
        def comments= comments
          @comments = comments
        end
        def comments
          @comments
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

class Library::Book
  include Library::Commentable

  attr_accessor :author, :title
  def initialize author, title
    @author = author
    @title = title
  end
end

o = Library::Book.new 'Мария Эрих Ремарк', 'Три товарища'
o.comments = []
p o.comments
```

Однако, как уже упомянул D-side, гораздо более элегантно задачу можно решить при помощи метода `prepend`, который позволяет решить задачу более элегантно

```
module Library
  module Commentable
    attr_accessor :comments
    def initialize author, title
      @author = author
      @title = title
      @comments = []
    end
  end
end

class Library::Book
  prepend Library::Commentable

  attr_accessor :author, :title
  def initialize author, title
    @author = author
    @title = title
  end
end

o = Library::Book.new 'Мария Эрих Ремарк', 'Три товарища'
p o.comments
p o.author
```

В последнем примере вы затираете метод `Library::Book#initialize` методом `Library::Commentable#initialize`. Здесь это смысла не имеет - так как пример очень компактный, но если вам нужно где-то на лету изменить поведение класса, его можно открыть и "поправить" при помощи вашего модуля

```
class Library::Book
  prepend Library::Commentable
end
```

Comment: Хм, нет, `prepend` не затрёт `initialize`, он просто будет стоять **перед** соответствующим методом самого класса, `super` подействует так же, просто в обратную сторону. Если, конечно, его использовать. Иначе да, будет выглядеть, будто исходный метод пропал.